# Rails refers to wrong model on create with nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, nested, rails-activerecord

I have a model called `Foo`, and a nested model called `Foo::Type`. I want to create a new `Foo` with a `foo_type_id` of 42. I can call `Foo.new(foo_type_id: 42)`, but when I try to call `#save` on that, I get the error `Uninitialized constant Foo::FooType`. How can I clarify to rails what I mean?

My model folder looks like this (a hyphen indicates a file):

```
models
  - foo.rb
    foo
      - type.rb
```

My `Foo::Type` model is empty, and my `Foo` model just `belongs_to :foo_type`

### Steps to reproduce

```
rails new sampleapp
cd sampleapp
rails g model foo/type name:text
rails g model foo foo_type:references
rails db:migrate
rails c # The next steps should be in IRB
Foo::Type.create(name: 'Test Type')
Foo.new(foo_type_id: 1).save
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're `Foo` model needs to know that `foo_type` refers to `Foo::Type` instead of the default assumption, `FooType`. To do that, in your `Foo` model, when you setup the `belongs_to` relationship, you need to say `belongs_to :foo_type, class_name: "Foo::Type"`. This tells `Foo` how to find the `Foo::Type` model.